# Magento - Back link to catalog page or filtered by category from product details page

Tags: magento, product, catalog

Need to add the "back link" to the catalog page from the product details page.

If the user has filtered product, the filter settings should be preserved.

Comment: If the product search result has been filtered further by category, price.. or more, and viewed the product details page, then the back link (i.e. "Back to Previous Page") on the product page should be returned to the search result page with the filtered result that has been previously selected.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with javascript

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go Back like never before</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In very general terms, look at the `HTTP_REFERER` header. Just be aware that some folken (like myself) don't use it.